# Is it possible to replace values inside json?

Tags: kql

Is it possible to manipulate a nested property inside a Json? For example, I want to Set the 'company' property to "Google"

```
datatable(d:dynamic)[
dynamic({'Person': { 'Name' : 'DuDu', 'SuperPower' : 'Kql', 'Company' : { 'Name' : 'Microsoft' }}}),] | project bag_merge(pack("Person.Company.Name", 'Google'), d)
```

So that after the manipulation, d will be :

{
"Person": {
"Name": "DuDu",
"SuperPower": "Kql",
"Company": {
"Name": "Google"
}
}
}

Answer (score 1):

you could use a combination of [`bag_set_key()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bag-set-key-function) and [`bag_remove_keys()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/bag-remove-keys-function).

for example:

```
datatable(d:dynamic)[
    dynamic(
        {
            "Person": {
                "Name": "DuDu",
                "SuperPower": "Kql",
                "Company": {
                "Name": "Microsoft"
                }
            }
        }
    )
]
| project modified_bag = bag_set_key(bag_remove_keys(d, dynamic(["Person.Company.Name"])), "$.Person.Company.Name", "Google")
```

| modified_bag |
| --- |
| { "Person": { "Name": "DuDu", "SuperPower": "Kql", "Company": { "Name": "Google" } } } |